HuggingFace pipeline doesn't use multiple GPUs
I made a RAG app that basically answers user questions based on provided data, it works fine on GPU and a single GPU. I want to deploy it on multiple GPUs (4 T4s) but I always get CUDA out of Memory error on pipeline.
I tried using "auto" keyword too but Langchain does not let me use it as keyword.
I used Langchain as main framework, my code looks like this:
from langchain_huggingface import ChatHuggingFace, HuggingFacePipeline, HuggingFaceEmbeddings
MODEL_NAME="mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3"
pipe = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(
                           model_id=MODEL_NAME,
                           device=0,
                           model_kwargs={"torch_dtype":torch.float16},
                           task="text-generation")
llm = ChatHuggingFace(llm=pipe)

embedding = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=MODEL_NAME,
                                  model_kwargs={"device":"cuda:1"},
                                  multi_process=True,
                                  )


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.
